# How do you represent a json array in an html form

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Note: i am also using [AspNetBoilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/)'s template and [Mecons](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/) tag helpers so `bc-` attributes and `form-group` tags are valid.

I'm trying to post a model to one of my application services. But im getting the following errors

> "The following errors were detected during validation.
>   ↵ - Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[App.Stores.StoreWalk.Dtos.CreateOrEditStoreWalkCategoryDto]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   ↵To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>   ↵Path 'categories.0', line 1, position 84.
>   ↵"message: "Your request is not valid!"validationErrors: [{…}]**proto**: Object

I understand what the error means, I just dont know how to fix my code.

Out of the 2 recommendations, `To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])` would be the path I'd have to take.

Probally irellevant but i was playing with my code and noticed when i remove `@i` and `@j` from my `name` attribute, i am able to post successfully, but my radio buttons lost all functionality (clicking second row changes first row due to naming conflict), also, i would think the index would be needed to keep them unique (im still learning, correct me if im wrong).

The json string that im posting back is created by calling `$('form[name=StoreWalkForm]').serializeFormToObject()` which looks like below and utilizes https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON

```
$.fn.serializeFormToObject = function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    var fields = $form.find('[disabled]');
    fields.prop('disabled', false);
    var json = $form.serializeJSON();
    fields.prop('disabled', true);
    return json;
};
```

#### JSON

```
{
  "version": "2",
  "department": {
    "id": "8",
    "name": "ISF"
  },
  "store": "001",
  "categories": {
    "0": {
      "category": {
        "id": "4"
      },
      "questions": {
        "0": {
          "question": {
            "question": "SIGNAGE",
            "id": "233"
          },
          "answer": {
            "boolValue": "false",
            "comments": "1"
          }
        },
        "1": {
          "question": {
            "question": "PARKING LOT BLACKTOP",
            "id": "234"
          },
          "answer": {
            "boolValue": "true",
            "comments": "2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "comments": "123",
  "signature": ""
}
```

#### Model Class

```
public class CreateOrEditStoreWalkDto : EntityDto<int?>
{
    [Required]
    public string Store { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public byte[] Signature { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    public DepartmentsDto Department { get; set; }

    public IList<CreateOrEditStoreWalkCategoryDto> Categories { get; set; } = new List<CreateOrEditStoreWalkCategoryDto>();
}

public class CreateOrEditStoreWalkCategoryDto
{
    public CategoriesDto Category { get; set; }
    public IList<CreateOrEditStoreWalkQuestionDto> Questions { get; set; } = new List<CreateOrEditStoreWalkQuestionDto>();
}

public class CreateOrEditStoreWalkQuestionDto
{
    public QuestionsDto Question { get; set; }
    public AnswersDto Answer { get; set; }
}
```

CSHtml

```
    <form name="StoreWalkInformationsForm" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate class="form-validation">

        @if (Model.IsEditMode)
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Id" />
        }

        <input type="hidden" name="version" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Version" />
        <input type="hidden" name="department[id]" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Id" />
        <input type="hidden" name="department[name]" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Department.Name" />

        <form-group>
            <select id="StoreWalk_Store" name="store" bc-label="@L("Store")" required="required" bc-required="true" bc-validation="true" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Store" maxlength="@App.Stores.StoreWalk.EntriesConsts.MaxStoreLength" minlength="@App.Stores.StoreWalk.EntriesConsts.MinStoreLength">
                @if (!Model.IsEditMode)
                {
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                }
            </select>
        </form-group>

        <br /><br />

        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.StoreWalk.Categories.Count; i++)
        {
            <h5 class="m--font-primary">@Model.StoreWalk.Categories[i].Category.Name</h5>
            <input type="hidden" name="categories[@i][category][id]" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Categories[i].Category.Id" />

            <table bc-responsive="true">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Question</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                        <th scope="col">Comments</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    @*@for (var j = 0; j < Model.StoreWalk.Categories[i].Questions.Count; j++)*@
                        @for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@(q.Next()).</td>
                                <td scope="row">
                                    <form-group>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="categories[@i][questions][@j][question][question]" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Categories[i].Questions[j].Question.Question" bc-label="@Model.StoreWalk.Categories[i].Questions[j].Question.Question" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="categories[@i][questions][@j][question][id]" value="@Model.StoreWalk.Categories[i].Questions[j].Question.Id" />
                                        <br />
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StoreWalk.Categories[i].Questions[j].S3Files, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple" })
                                    </form-group>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <form-group>
                                        <radio-list bc-required="true" bc-validation="true" id="categories[@i][questions][@j][answer][boolValue]">
                                            <input type="radio" name="categories[@i][questions][@j][answer][boolValue]" value="true" bc-label="@L("Yes")" required="required" />
                                            <input type="radio" name="categories[@i][questions][@j][answer][boolValue]" value="false" bc-label="@L("No")" required="required" />
                                        </radio-list>
                                    </form-group>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <form-group>
                                        <textarea name="categories[@i][questions][@j][answer][comments]" rows="3">@Model.StoreWalk.Categories[i].Questions[j].Answer.Comments</textarea>
                                    </form-group>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }


        <form-group>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="StoreWalk_Comments" type="text" name="comments" bc-label="@L("Comments")" rows="4">@Model.StoreWalk.Comments</textarea>
        </form-group>

        <form-group>
            <label for="signature">@L("Signature")</label>
            @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Shared/Views/Shared/SignaturePad/Edit.cshtml", new SignaturePadModel()
            {
                Id = "signature",
                Data = Model.StoreWalk.Signature,
                FooterText = L("Signature"),
                Required = true
            })
        </form-group>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `{useIntKeysAsArrayIndex: true}` into `$form.serializeJSON()`.

```js
$.fn.serializeFormToObject = function() {
    var $form = $(this);
    var fields = $form.find('[disabled]');
    fields.prop('disabled', false);

 // var json = $form.serializeJSON();
    var json = $form.serializeJSON({useIntKeysAsArrayIndex: true});

    fields.prop('disabled', true);
    return json;
};
```

---

From https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON linked in the question:

> ### Use integer keys as array indexes
>
> ```html
> <form>
>   <input type="text" name="arr[0]" value="foo"/>
>   <input type="text" name="arr[1]" value="var"/>
>   <input type="text" name="arr[5]" value="inn"/>
> </form>
> ```
>
> ```js
> $('form').serializeJSON();
>
> // arr is an object =>
> {'arr': {'0': 'foo', '1': 'var', '5': 'inn' }}
> ```
>
> ```js
> $('form').serializeJSON({useIntKeysAsArrayIndex: true});
>
> // arr is an array =>
> {'arr': ['foo', 'var', undefined, undefined, undefined, 'inn']}
> ```